# How to enable "Validate Plugin in set" in Eclipse helios

Tags: java, eclipse

How to access "Validate plugin set" in Eclipse Helios.
The same can be accessed in Eclipse 3.2 which is available on the “Plug-ins" tab of a launch configuration.
I need to enable "Validate plugin set" in order to validate my dependency automatically prior to launching..

Do i need to download some plugin to view that option?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be an Eclipse Application, or a Runtime Workbench, but it's still there.